# Execute script between Msi packages during bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7, burn

I want to execute a command prompt script after a certain MSI/EXE package has been installed, but before another executes. Is there a way to do this using the bootstrapper?

I cannot edit the MSI/EXE to include the script, but I need to execute the script in between the installers.

Answer (score 4):

The default WIX BA does not support calling custom actions, but you always have the option of customizing the bootstrapper.

Make a small c# console application which starts the cmd process and do what you want to do. Include it in your bootstrapper between the MSI's.

I think that would be easier than editing the bootstrapper.

Comment: I agree this is the simplest way to do it. You don't even need an executable though. It's possible to reference a batch script in an `ExePackage` element as if it were an executable.